# Setting JVM_ARGS for Payara server in docker-compose

Tags: docker, jvm-arguments, payara

How can I set a Payara servers jvm-option in docker compose?

For the application I use the payara/server-full:5.194 container.
I know that I have to use the `JVM_ARGS` ENV Variable, but I don't know how exactly.

This is a piece of my docker-compose.yml file:

```
version: "3.5"
services:    
    myApplication:
       build:
          context: .
          dockerfile: Dockerfile
       image: myApplication:latest
       environment:
        POSTBOOT_COMMANDS: /tmp/init_asadmin_commands.sh
        JVM_ARGS: -DmyApplication.home.dir=/msc/srv/myApplication
       ports:
         - "8080:8080"
         - "4848:4848"
```

Does anybody has an example for me? (I haven't found a good usage)

Thanks!

Edit(1):

This is the error what i get on docker-compse up:

```
sed: -e expression #1, char 54: unknown option to `s'
```

And this is what I found, how the container uses it:

```
COMMAND=`echo "$OUTPUT"\
 | sed -n -e '2,/^$/p'\
 | sed 's/glassfish.jar/glassfish.jar '"$JVM_ARGS"'/' `
```

Comment: Do you get any error messages? I would expect that you need to put the args in quotation marks, i.e. `VM_ARGS: "-DmyApplication.home.dir=/msc/srv/myApplication"`

Comment: @ChristophJohn I tried your option, also added the error i get.

Comment: Oh OK, wenn `sed` is used on that it might be that you need to escape the slashes. So `"-DmyApplication.home.dir=\/msc\/srv\/myApplication"`

Comment: Thanks! It worked this way. '-DmyApplication.home.dir=\/msc\/srv\/myApplication'
But when i look for it in the Payara's admin console (on localhost:4848) I can't seet it in the JVM Settings/JVM Options

Comment: And what if I want to pass multiple arguments to this ENV Variable?

Comment: Got it! This way:
JVM_ARGS: '-myApp.home.dir=\/msc\/srv\/myApp -Dother.application.porp=something -Dthird.application.property=myproperty'
Just spaces between them :)